# Advice needed on handling HTML form data across multiple forms

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created two HTML forms of which both ask for a customers name & telephone with the other form fields asking for different information because they are for different services.

Both forms can be completed individually without the other being completed for example, form 1 needs to be completed if a customer is purchasing a brand new product & then if they want to take out maintenance on that product they tick a checkbox & it takes them to form 2 which asks for some of the same information so to save them entering all that information again I want it to display their previous input info in the fields to show they no longer need to enter it again.

However, they may not want to purchase a new product as they already have one but want to take out maintenance therefore they can fill in form 2 from a blank form.

So I am after the best method to approach this whether it's with PHP or JavaScript.

Sorry for the long winded explanation.

Thx.
Lee.

Comment: I'd recommend doing it all in one page, with the maintenance inputs all hidden (wrapped in a hidden div, for example), and then show them if the checkbox is ticked.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are asking for code examples or just advice, for now I'm just going with the latter.

Why not just fill the second form with the contents of the first when the checkbox is checked? If the customer isn't buying anything, there won't be any contents anyway, so it should display as blank, shouldn't it?

Comment: I was thinking of using PHP sessions but my worry there is if that same customer only wants to complete the maintenance form then that form will be looking for user data which won't exist from the first form.  So how would I handle starting and terminating sessions if that makes sense?  Ideally I want to keep form results separate and not emailed as one big form.

Answer (score 0):

Use JS to handle the form side of things and then feed that into a PHP service. You can handle all the form processing on the JS side and just have a PHP method take all the information if isset and proceed. Best way from a UI perspective.